# QT c++ Http запрос

Tags: c++, qt, http, qt5, httpclient

Пытаюсь получить текст с сайта, но работает только один раз, при следующим разе ничего не выводит

```
#include "httpwebapi.h"

HttpWebAPI::HttpWebAPI(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QString HttpWebAPI::HttpReturn(QString http)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkReply *httpReturn = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(http)));
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QObject::connect(httpReturn,SIGNAL(finished()),&eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    eventLoop.exec();
    return QString::fromUtf8(httpReturn->readAll());
}
```

Comment: А сделать по человечески не пробовали? зачем каждый раз создавать QNetworkAccessManager, не удалять после себя QNetworkReply, и вообще блокировать эвентлуп?

Comment: а как иначе создать глючное тормозное приложение? надо начинать с самых основ.

Comment: QNetworkReply очищается сразу после того как вы читаете из него данные, я бы на вашем месте использовал  всего один QNetworkAccessManager на весь проект или весь класс